# I am unable to save clob data in mysql hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate and MySql and using the following code to insert data into clob:

```html
Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();            
String updateavatar="update contact set AVATAR=:rawContent where id =:id";
Query updatequery = session.createSQLQuery(updateavatar);
updatequery.setString("rawContent", data);
updatequery.setLong("id",id);
updatequery.executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
factory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
```

in a servlet filter i start the transaction on currentSession. In order to be able to handle other issues I commit immediately which will close transaction and the session,, so i start it again after commit to keep a single session for the page being rendered.

But nothing is saved in database.  Prior to this code i was using the following code:

```html
    Session session=factory.openSession();            
    String updateavatar="update contact set AVATAR=:rawContent where id =:id";
    Query updatequery = session.createSQLQuery(updateavatar);
    updatequery.setString("rawContent", data);
    updatequery.setLong("id",id);
    updatequery.executeUpdate();
    session.commit();
```

this code was working fine and i could have data saved in database...

Is there something i should add to make it work, or is there another way to insert data in database for clob type?

Comment: why would you rape hibernate by using native sql?

Comment: Is it something i should not do? i am not familiar with Hibernate and trying ad hoc at every step i am taking.